# How to use PixelWriter.setPixels()?

Tags: java, javafx, parameters

this should be quite an easy question for most of you.
How do I properly set the parameters of PixelWriter.setPixel()?

I have tried to find it out for an hour now. I have of course also seen sites like that 
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html

setPixels(int x,int y,int w,int h,PixelFormat pixelformat,T buffer,int scanlineStride)

I know how to use the x and y parameter. And I think I know how to use the w and h parameter. But I have no idea how to use the rest.

I can't even manage to get it to work somehow.

Please be gentle I am a beginner.

Edit: Drawing works now, but the color is still not black. It's light blue somehow. Any ideas?

```
    public final void drawLine(int xStart, int yStart, final int xEnd, final int yEnd, final Color c) {

    // Variables declaration
    this.xStart = xStart;
    this.yStart = yStart;
    this.xEnd = xEnd;
    this.yEnd = yEnd;

    // Getting the PixelWriter from the Canvas
    this.pw = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().getPixelWriter();

    /**
     * TODO Bresenham Implementation
     */
    final WritablePixelFormat<ByteBuffer> format = WritablePixelFormat.getByteBgraPreInstance();

    double dx = xEnd - xStart;
    double dy = yEnd - yStart;

    double error=dx/2.0;

    byte imageData[] = new byte[300];

    System.out.println("Red: "+c.getRed()+"\tGreen: "+c.getGreen()+"\tBlue: "+c.getBlue());  // R=0, G=0, B=0  (black)

    for ( int i = 0;i<100;i++) {
        int k = 0;
          imageData[i]=(byte) c.getRed();
          imageData[i+1]=(byte) c.getGreen();
          imageData[i+2]=(byte) c.getBlue();
          k+=3;
          pw.setPixels(i, i, 1, 1, format,imageData, 0, 1);
    }
```

Comment: Check out this https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/image_ops/jfxpub-image_ops.htm it has some nice simple examples

Comment: You probably want one of the other forms of `setPixels(...)`. Presumably you have some data that you want to render into an image. What form are those data in? (rgb int values, bytes, ...?)

Comment: Well I want to use the Bresenham-Algorithm to draw simple lines. Pixel per pixel. I thought I could paint every single pixel after each iteration. I am not sure what data that would be.

Comment: You need to decide how the data will be represented. Typically you would either use three bytes per pixel (representing the red, green, and blue values for that pixel, respectively), or a single int with the red, green, and blue values encoded into bits in the int. (Similar options exist if you include an alpha channel.) Then assemble those data into an array. The `PixelFormat` argument specifies how the data are encoded: you can just use one of the predefined options (e.g. `PixelFormat.getByteRgbInstance()`).

Comment: That was helpful. And how would I use the buffer argument?  I entered for scanlineStride argument a "1" and the method did accept that. Why is that? What exactly would it do with a 1?

Comment: The `setPixels(...)` methods taking arrays (either arrays of bytes or arrays of ints) are designed to set the pixels in an entire rectangular area, not just a single pixel. To set a single pixel, you could just use the `setArgb(...)` method or the `setColor(...)` method. The code in your edit is also going to produce incorrect results because 1. you have specified a premultiplied format, and 2. you have specified a bgra format but not set an alpha byte. The `scanlineStride` parameter is the increase in array index in going from one row to the next in the array you specify (4 in your case).